mypy/pyright do not warn about undefined class attribute
class A:
    def set_this_or_everything_breaks(self) -> None:
        self.important_variable = "c"

    def run(self) -> None:
        print(f"this is what is important {self.important_variable.lower()}")

a = A()
a.run()

Why does mypy not complain about self.important_variable being undefined? How can I make it complain? If I remove set_this_or_everything_breaks it'll complain but it should be complaining. Can I force all class attributes to be defined on the class? I would expect that I'd get a possibly undefined error here.

Oh wow. I could have sworn that mypy would consider a attribute not to exist unless it was assigned to in __init__ or explicitly type annotated at the class level. But I guess not

I wish there were at least some --strict option for this

@juanpa.arrivillaga From the documentation you referenced, it seems like it should throw an error, doesn't it? "The mypy type checker detects if you are trying to access a missing attribute"

@lord_haffi no, because somewhere in your class definition you have self. important_variable = 'c'. But mypy won't actualy make sure that method is called (such a thing would typically be beyond the scope of a static type checker anyway). Maybe there are linters that would detect this (certainly, tehre are linters that force you to define your attributes in __init__)

@juanpa.arrivillaga You're right. Even Pycharm is ok with it. It doesn't mark a warning unlike when the method is removed. But using pylint, it would throw "W0201: Attribute 'important_variable' defined outside init (attribute-defined-outside-init)"

@lord_haffi yeah, this is unfortunately why you cannot just rely on mypy or pyright. Fundamentally, you just need to not write classes like this. Which ends up being an issue of maintaining code standards and code review.

@juanpa.arrivillaga exactly, this class is horrible. I was typing out an example of how type checking encourages good code (because you'd get yelled at for writing a bad class like this), then I didn't get any errors :(. InSync seems to have provided a solution. I'll check in on that after I make up for time I spent tangenting on this this morning haha.

Pyright does have an option for this: reportUninitializedInstanceVariable.

Generate or suppress diagnostics for instance variables within a class that are not initialized or declared within the class body or the __init__ method.

It is off even in strict mode, so you need to explicitly enable it:
// pyrightconfig.json
{
    "reportUninitializedInstanceVariable": "warning"
}

# pyproject.toml
[tool.pyright]
reportUninitializedInstanceVariable = "warning"


great find. makes me more inclined to use pyright with this setting over mypy. I still use both
